# How to flatten a nested list?

Tags: python, list, recursion

Hi I am troubling with this problem and I want to flatten a nested list.
Here is my code but it does not work can someone help me please

```
def paps(lst):
    if lst == []:
        return lst
    if type(lst[0]) == list:
        return paps(lst[0])+ paps(lst[1:])
    else:
        return lst[:1] + paps(lst[1:])
```

My problem must be with recursion.

Comment: Your code is working for me.

Comment: Can you put your output please

Comment: I ran it with `a=[1,[2,[3,[4,5]]]]` and got `[1,2,3,4,5]` as my result.